# How to prevent page refresh on Page Changing in Asp.Net Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Grid View inside the Update Panel. 
But when i change the page of Grid View, it post backs and refresh the page.

Here is my Asp.Net Control:

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:GridView ID="gvLeads" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="mydatagrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pager"
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="2" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No Leads Found" PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages" AllowSorting="True"
          OnPageIndexChanging="gvLeads_PageIndexChanging" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="true">
                <Columns>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="LeadId" HeaderText="Id" />
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="LeadTitle" HeaderText="Title" />
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" />
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="StatusTitle" HeaderText="Status" />
                </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
   </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdateLeadMaster" />
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvLeads" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />
      </Triggers>  
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And here is the Page Index Changing Event:

```
  protected void gvLeads_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
  {
            gvLeads.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            gvLeads.DataSource = dtLead;
            gvLeads.DataBind();
   }
```

Is there something wrong with my code? or whats causing this issue?

Comment: Add `ChildrenAsTriggers=false` to update panel

Comment: still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Grid view will work with update panel, only if the `EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks` is `false`.

Hope this help!